# How to append innerhtml using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Basically i am using ionic angular to make a qr code scanner. On scanning i want anything that starts with "http" to get hyperlinked and everything else to be normally formatted so i created a function to split the output and check for "http". The if & else statements are working fine.
html file :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary" >
    <ion-title>
      QR Scanner
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>Result :</ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-item *ngIf="scannedCode" >
              {{checkForURL()}}
          </ion-item>
          <ion-button (click)="scanCode()" fill="outline" id="btn-enter" size="default" ><ion-icon name="qr-code-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>Scan Again</ion-button>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

and here is the code to the ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx'
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NullVisitor } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  scannedCode = "";


  constructor(private barcodeScanner : BarcodeScanner,
    private navCtrl : NavController) {}

  scanCode(){
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(
      barcodeData => {
        this.scannedCode = barcodeData.text;
      }
    )
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.scanCode();
    
  } 
  
  str2 = this.scannedCode.split(':',4)
  checkForURL(){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = this.scannedCode;
      a.title = this.scannedCode; 
      document.body.appendChild(a);
    }else{
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      var node = document.createTextNode(this.scannedCode);
      document.body.appendChild(para);
      para.appendChild(node);
  }
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides you a way to inject HTML using [innerHTML] attribute (in your case something like `<span [innerHTML]="getLink()"></span>`). The method `getLink()` would return a stringified HTML element (e.g. `<a href="link">My link</a>`

However, this approach is not the best - for example it is quite hard to style elements injected this way. A better way would be this:

1. Inside the `ion-item` element, create `<a>` element
2. Dynamically inject HREF attribute to this element using your `checkForURL` function

This would look like this:

.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  scannedCode = null;
  scannedCodeLink = null;
  scanCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(
      barcodeData => {
        this.scannedCode = barcodeData.text;
        this.scannedCodeLink = this.checkForUrl();
      }
    );
  }
  private checkForUrl() : string {
    return this.scannedCode.includes('http') ? this.scannedCode : null;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<ion-item *ngIf="scannedCode" >
  <a [href]="scannedCodeLink">{{scannedCode}}</a>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: how do i dynamically inject href into the a tag ?

Comment: I think the best way would be formatting the URL everytime the scanner "picks up" some new value. I will update my answer

Comment: it asks me to add a return statement to the checkforurl function, on adding it, it hyperlinks everything that is scanned, irrespective of the http

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad :) I fixed the issue

Comment: still not working, it converts everything to hyperlink, thanks for helping man i really appreciate it